# Decimal module: rounding

Tags: python, decimal

I have some trouble getting the desired values.

The following 'abc' strings represent angles.
The 'result' strings represents the values I'm looking for.

```
a = '199.1224'
result = '199.122400000000000'

b = '199.0362'
result = '199.036200000000010'

c = '-199.9591'
result = '-199.959100000000010'
```

I use the following code:

```
Decimal(float(a)).quantize(Decimal('.000000000000001'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)

results in 
a = 199.122399999999999
b = 199.036200000000008
c = -199.959100000000007
```

I'm no math genius, and tried almost everything possible in the Decimal module, but I can't seem to find the right way to get the result I need.

As a crappy workaround I use:

```
Decimal(float(a)).quantize(Decimal('.00000000000001'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)
str(a)+'0'
```

So quantize with one less decimal, convert to string (have to do that anyway) and add a zero.
This gets me the correct desired results with thousands of these values.
But I want to find out if there is a correct way to round and end with a zero (don't know the english words for this).

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want. It seems that either the first result should be `'199.122400000000010'` or the second should be  `'199.036200000000000'`.

Comment: 'abc' are the input numbers.
the results represent the values i'm looking to accomplish.
I'm trying to simulate a software tool that does exactly this.

The problem is that results like:
    a = 199.122399999999999
    b = 199.036200000000008
    c = -199.959100000000007

Are not precise enough.
I have no clue how the software converts these numbers and I can't find out somehow.

Comment: I'm confused, why does the desired result for `a` end in `00` while the desired result for `b` ends in `10`?

Comment: So in the end, to rephrase my question:
If i have a = 199.036200000000008
Is it possible to round down to 199.036200000000010 , so ending with a zero, without tricks like the workaround I use.

Comment: @flornquake If you look at the values and the place where the rounding takes place you see why (I used []):  

- >>> Decimal(199.0362) Decimal('199.0362000000000[08]00355337560176849365234375')  

- >>> Decimal(199.1224) Decimal('199.1223999999999[98]954081092961132526397705078125')

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import decimal
from decimal import Decimal

b = '199.0362'
result = Decimal(float(b)).quantize(Decimal('0e-14'), rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
print format(result, '.15f')

# a:  '199.1224' ->  '199.122400000000000'
# b:  '199.0362' ->  '199.036200000000010'
# c: '-199.9591' -> '-199.959100000000010'
```

- If you use `'0e-14'` instead of `'0.00000000000001'` in `quantize`, you don't have to count the digits to check that it's correct.
- Use the `format` function to convert to a string with a specific number of decimal places.

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm! I didn't understand the format function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in using `float(a)`.  The float type does not have exact representation for most terminating decimal fractions.  I used:

```
from decimal import *
b = '199.0362'
Decimal(float(b)).quantize(Decimal('.000000000000001'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)
Decimal(b).quantize(Decimal('.000000000000001'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)
```

and get `Decimal('199.036200000000008')`, just like you did on the first one, but `Decimal('199.036200000000000')` on the second.  So...what is the float() conversion doing for you that you can't just use the second version?

If you need to get input from a computed floating point result, remember that you only get about 52 bits of significance, or about 52*log10(2) ~~ 15.6 decimal digits.  So the 16'th signficant digit is probably not rounded correctlyThat's usually taken to be 15 for practical purposes.  You can get that rounded result in a string with the format function:

```
format(float(b), ".15g")
```

That will suppress trailing fractional zeros, and switch to scientific notation when that's more convenient. But it will get the result rounded to 15 significant digits.  You may have to format the result of that to the desired number of fixed decimal places:

```
d = Decimal(float(b), ".15g")
print ("d = " + format(d, ".12f"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this indeed, but as you can see in my comment above, I need the numbers to be exactly as described. In that case, i'm starting to believe my workaround ain't that bad after all.